# If there is no intermolecular forces in a medium, then can transverse waves propagate through the medium?

Tags: forces, waves, oscillators

I am talking about waves which require a medium.

If there is no intermolecular forces in a medium, then can *transverse waves* propagate through that medium?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfv%C3%A9n_wave

Comment: Aren't there electromagnetic interactions between the ions in such a wave?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A wave would require acceleration of the molecules in the medium. Some force would have to produce that acceleration.

If the force isn't intermolecular, then it must come from outside the medium. It's easy enough to think of examples where that might happen -- eg the medium could respond to a passing electrical field -- but I don't think it would qualify as *propagation*.